# how to put here hyperlink for this date?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vuex

How to put here hyperlink for this date? I want this random date to lead me to some random internet-link

```
<v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>
                02.06.2023
            </v-list-item-title>
</v-list-item-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the date in an anchor tag.

```html
<v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>
           <a href="http://www.google.com">02.06.2023</a>
            </v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
```